# master slave crashing daily

Tags: mysql

I have implemented a master slave config several times and each time the process goes well and works for a day or two but soon bombs out saying that replication stopped because such and such table does not exist.

relevant part of my.cnf:

```
[client]
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
server-id                       = 2
master-host                     = 10.10.10.33
master-connect-retry            = 60
master-user                     = repl
master-password                 = redacted
relay-log                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
relay-log-index                 = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
log-error                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.err
master-info-file                = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-master.info
relay-log-info-file             = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-log.info
log_bin                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_format                   = ROW
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
pid-file                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
binlog_format                   = row
max_connections                 = 200
max_connect_errors              = 1000
key_buffer_size                 = 256M
```

There are numerous instances where the slave reports that such and such table doesnt exist in a given database but in fact it does exist.

Any ideas on what may be causing this or ways to improve stability ? In case it matters, this mysql server is housing 125 databases and is about 60gb in size total.

Comment: uppercase/lower case issue on table names?

Comment: I thought about that. Any recommendations for my.cnf entries or procedure changes to alleviate that ?

Comment: How's your hardware and network?

Comment: seems ok to me. no issues that i can detect.

Comment: What ENGINE(s) are the "missing" tables?

Answer (score 0):

First you should check the error logs & post for clarification.
This can happen doue to-

```
Your slave database is differ to its master when replication start. 
So before replication sync both the server.
```

If your replication is statement type & replicate some specific database. ex-

```
use not_replica;
alter table replica.test ....
use replica;
insert into replica.test ...
```

here alter command for test would not replicate. because you are using not_replica database. after that insert statement would fail & replication stopped.